# expected value of getting couples on adjoining seats for b bachelors and m models

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Ref: The Theater Row Puzzle from the book Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability by Mosteller (1965) reads:

> "Eight eligible bachelors and seven beautiful models happen randomly
>   to have purchased single seats in the same 15-seat row of a theater.
>   On the average, how many pairs of adjacent seats are ticketed for
>   marriageable couples?"

I understand the solution of the book (explicited [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034837/expected-value-of-getting-couples-on-adjoining-seats-for-b-bachelors-and-m-model), it is v. helpful to have a look to understand the situation I think) and why and how we use linearity of expectations. My issue is that I tried to answer it looking at **chunks of 3 seats (rather considering pairs of seats)** and get a different result. What is wrong with my logic?

Consider a chunk of 3 seats: XYZ. Denote male by M, female by F. Consider only the possibilities where a non-zero number of couple arises.

You can have the case of 2 males: 
MFM, MMF, FMM (each with probability: $8/15*1/2*7/13 = .1436$) or 2 women: FMF, FFM, MFF (each with probability: $7/15*6/14*8/13 = .123$).

Computing expected value of number of couples for a 3-seat chunk:

$$.1436*2+.1436*1+.1436*1 + .123*2 + .123*1 + .123*1 = 1.0667$$

Now multiply this by 13 (the number of 3 seat chunks on a 15 seats row) and you get about twice as many couples as in the actual solution.

**What has gone wrong in my reasoning?**

Comment: What a splendidly pure example of sexism.

Comment: @Did, it was a different, less enlightened time (1965, when I checked). :)

Answer (score 0):

You're double-counting couples.  For example say that the row begins MMFF... ; you'll count the couple at positions 2 and 3 twice, one as part of the chunk MMF coming from positions 1-3 and one as part of the chunk MFF coming from positions 2-4.

Your answer comes out to be somewhat less than twice the correct answer because you don't double-count every couple.  In particular a couple at positions 1 and 2 or at positions 14 and 15 (i. e. at either end of the row) would only be counted once by your method.